# Turning off the Browser/Window Chrome for Prism app

Tags: web-applications, prism

I am currently working on a project requiring Prism to make a webapp. The question from the client that I am trying find out is whether there is a way to turn off the application chrome in Prism. I see you can turn off parts of the UI (location, status, sidebar, etc.), but not the entire chrome itself.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I am still combing through the documentation to see if I can find anything, but so for no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Out-of-browser mode. Here is explains: [link text](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/out-of-browser-applications/)

or you can open your application in the full screen mode:

```
    rootPage.LayoutRoot.MouseLeftButtonDown +=
    delegate(Object s, MouseButtonEventArgs args) {
        this.Host.Content.IsFullScreen =
            !this.Host.Content.IsFullScreen;
    };
```